# Get user followed topics in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am developing application where user can follow topics to get updates.

**Below are models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Topic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='topic')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Follow(models.Model):
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, related_name='follow')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='follow')
```

**views.py**

```
def home(req):
    user_id = req.user.id
    follow = Follow.objects.filter(user = req.user).all()
    follow = [f.topic for f in follow]
    question = Question.objects.filter(topic__in=follow).all()
    answer = Answer.objects.filter(ques__in=question).all()
    topic = Topic.objects.all().distinct(name)
    return render(req,'home.html',{'topic':topic,'answer':answer,'upvote':upvote})
```

**Template:**

```
            {% for t in topic %}   
                {% for ft in t.follow.all%}
                    {% if ft.user == user %}
                        <h4 id="{{t.pk}}" class="topCls"><span class="badge badge-success">{{t.name}}</span></h4>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            &nbsp;
            {% endfor %}
```

I need to get user followed topics in green color and other topics in red color

I can get user followed topics as above, How can i differentiate followed or not ?

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if topic in follow list like this:

```
{% for t in topic %}   
    {% if t in follow  %}
      <h4 id="{{t.pk}}" class="topCls"><span class="badge badge-success">{{t.name}}</span></h4>
    {% else %
      <h4 id="{{t.pk}}" class="topCls"><span class="badge badge-warning">{{t.name}}</span></h4>
    {% endif %}
&nbsp;
{% endfor %}
```

You need to pass `follow`list into context:

```
def home(req):
    user_id = req.user.id
    follow = Topic.objects.filter(follow__user=req.user)
    question = Question.objects.filter(topic__in=follow).all()
    answer = Answer.objects.filter(ques__in=question).all()
    topic = Topic.objects.all().distinct(name)
    return render(req,'home.html',{'topic':topic,'answer':answer,'upvote':upvote, 'follow': follow})
```